# How to remove undefined checkboxes generated by ng-repeat with modulo operation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have the following code (see below), it creates from a given list multiple checkboxes, by using `ng-if="$index % 3 == 0"`, I get 3 columns of checkboxes.

```
<div ng-controller="TestController" class="container">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0" class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="items[$index].id">&nbsp;
            <span>{{items[$index].name}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="items[$index+1].id">&nbsp;
            <span>{{items[$index+1].name}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="items[$index+2].id">&nbsp;
            <span>{{items[$index+2].name}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('app', [ ]);
app.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

     $scope.items = [
    {id:0, name:"1/4 Mile"},
    {id:1, name:"1/2 Mile"},
    {id:2, name:"1 Mile"},
    {id:3, name:"2 Mile"},
    {id:4, name:"3 Mile"},
    {id:5, name:"4 Mile"},
    {id:6, name:"5 Mile"}
  ];
}]);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vm3j4akp/1096/)

The problem is, that if the number of items in the list is odd, I get extra checkboxes that are blank/undefined. How can I avoid this?

Comment: check if `$index+1` is less than `items.length` (same for `+2` checkbox)

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `ng-if` condition. The last two blank checkbox is due to `items[$index+1]` and `items[$index+2]`. Since you have `$index % 3 == 0`  does not mean that `$index+1` and `$index+2` exist so you can have a `ng-if` condition to check that the value exists in `items` array.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [ ]);
app.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    {id:0, name:"1/4 Mile"},
    {id:1, name:"1/2 Mile"},
    {id:2, name:"1 Mile"},
    {id:3, name:"2 Mile"},
    {id:4, name:"3 Mile"},
    {id:5, name:"4 Mile"},
    {id:6, name:"5 Mile"}
  ];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TestController" class="container">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="items[$index].id">&nbsp;
      <span>{{items[$index].name}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-if='items[$index+1]' ng-model="items[$index+1].id">&nbsp;
      <span>{{items[$index+1].name}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-if='items[$index+2]' ng-model="items[$index+2].id">&nbsp;
      <span>{{items[$index+2].name}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```